# How to return an argument to function passed as props from parents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run a function in the parent after the user presses a button in the children.

It is running the function when the child is rendered instead of when it's clicked.

This is my parent:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.changeStatus = this.changeStatus.bind(this);
  }

  changeStatus(status) {
    console.log(status);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child
        statusChange={this.statusChange}
      />
    }
  }
}
```

This is my child

```
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    const { changeStatus } = this.props;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={changeStatus("go")}>
        <Text>Text</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `changeStatus !== statusChange`

Comment: @DimitarChristoff yes realized there was a typo... i changed it but it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a function not to call it inside `render`.

```
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    const { changeStatus } = this.props;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeStatus("go")}>
        <Text>Text</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

**UPD**

> is there a way to do it without an arrow function inside render

Normal function should work. `onPress={onPress}` where `function onPress() {...}`. Or you could use ES5ivy way `onPress={changeStatus.bind(this, 'go')}`

If you don't want to create a new function inside render at all you could do

```
class Child extends Component {

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
    this.changeStatus = this.changeStatus.bind(this)
  }
  changeStatus() {
     this.props.changeStatus('go')
  }
  render() {    
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeStatus}>
        <Text>Text</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks that works, is there a way to do it without an arrow function inside render?

Comment: @ShinonChan Yep. But you'll still need another function to be passed down as `onPress` handler. Check updated answer.